# IE6 bug, CSS, position absolute and height 100% inner DIV

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, height, absolute

I'm doing website and there I have 3 DIVs,

```
<div id="inner">
    <div id="content" >
             <div id="scroll" >
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now, div 'inner' is width and height - auto, position absolute;
'Content' have width:100%; height:100%;
And 'Scroll' is width: 96%; padding:2%; height: 96%; overflow: auto;

```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0 none;}
#scroll
{
    width: 96%;
    padding:2%;
    height: 96%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:18px;
    }

#inner { 
    position:absolute;
    background:none;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    top:40px;
    bottom:85px;
    right:10px;
    left:300px;
}
```

In Firefox, Opera IE8< everything is OK, but in IE6 and IE7 div 'scroll' is too long, height:100% doesn't work. [You can see it on the picture](http://studiosmok.pl/ie.jpg):

Anybody have a idea ? Please help me :)

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to a live page? It makes it much easier (in my opinion) to track down IE6 errors. On the subject of IE6 - are you sure that you still care about this ancient browser?

Comment: I will provide a link to a live page tomorrow, now I don't have password etc for server... More important is IE7 - this same bug how IE6

Answer (score 1):

IE7 has this bug too.

The only workaround i could found is, set the `#content-element` also to `position:absolute`.

Answer (score -1):

for 100% height in IE you need to add this to your CSS.

```
* html #content{
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: He already has `#content { height:100% }`. How will serving the same thing to only IE6 help?

Comment: It doesn't work, but I add something like this:
#inner {height:78.1%; display: block;}
Maybe it isn't exactly what I want, but effect is satisfying... If you have any idea, please write this.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure, but I think maybe using "inherit" for height property solves the problem.